# Python Program Take Memory In Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

*On ur linux machine  runaway phython program is writing a large 1 TB file afraid of filling your disk you del the file with an "rm" command in your shell, while the program is still running,*

**what happens to the phython program?**

**What happens to ur disk?**

**What happens to the file?**

Comment: what happen when this condition

Comment: I suggest you read about the standard *nix [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command, and the TERM signal.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the script from your disk will have no effect on it once it's running. And if you were trying to stop a runaway binary executable by deleting it from disk you'd be out of luck, too. So even deleting the Python executable itself from the disk won't stop a runaway Python script.

There are various ways to stop or pause processes on a Linux system. I suggest you read the man page for the [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command. Also see the section on Job Control in the Bash man page.

Comment: thanks but plz give asn

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary: Sorry, I don't know what your comment means.